# Unable to install app from TestFlight (works fine from Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store, testflight

I'm trying to install my app from TestFlight.

When I press `INSTALL`, **the download indicator runs for a sec and then stops**.

I can see the app on my phone, clicking on the app raises

> Unable to install the app, please try again later.

[image]

It's very weird, since **I run the app on a physical device using Xcode**, and everything was just fine. Also, **older versions of the app are downloaded from TestFlight without any problem**.

The app passed through all checks before uploading to the store.

**How is it possible that I cannot install the app from TestFight?**

What can I do in order to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This can be happen with number of reasons as given below:

- Might be you are using the developer profile instead of Adhoc profile
- OR using an app identifier that is different from the one that belongs to your profile
- OR might be an issue in enable/disable of  iCloud and Gamecenter

What you can do is you can connect the device to PC/Mac. Open the iPhone Configuration Utility and see the logs after you press install from the build in TestFlight. It will helps you to dig it.

And last hope is this issue can be at apple side as many developer are facing as given below: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/26759

Comment: I do had an issue with some certificates and profiles but after solving it, I still faced the same issue

Answer (score 0):

**It's not the correct answer.**

In case you are in a rash, and your project was already uploaded from another Mac to the store, a temporary solution will be to import the project to a well-configured Xcode from another computer and send it configured back to your computer. Make sure you have all necessary certificates, Build, and upload to the store. Then I was able to run the app on TestFlight and upload new updates without problems.

IMO, Apple did a really bad job connecting and configuring Xcode projects to the store. As a Flutter developer, I upload apps for both App Store and Play Store, and working with Apple is frustrating. There were no logs or indications about this issue, and it's almost impossible to track the mistake.